# Android: count days from a given time without relying on OS time

Tags: android, time, service, timer

In my app I need to update an object if the user didn't refresh it for 30 days. I tried several things to approach this, but none of them worked

**1. Using `System.currentTimeMillies()`**

My first try was to just store the time when the object was updated and compare it to the current time. Everything worked fine, but the problem was, that the user could change the os time and then the time check would be useless...

**2. Using `AlarmManager`**

Here I had the same problem as above

**3. Implementing a Service that contains a timer**

Here I implemented a `Service` with a Timer that just counts up to 30 days. This seemed to be the best solution, but the Service stops when I close the app. 
the `onCreate` and `onStartCommand` of my Service look like this (I just changed 30 days to 2 minutes for testing and it contains multiple timers for multiple objects):

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "[onCreate]");
    super.onCreate();
    registerReceiver(new StopServiceReceiver(), new IntentFilter(STOP_SERVICE_REQUEST));
    context = this;

    //retrieveTimers();
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[onStartCommand] intent = null");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    //prevent starting 2 timers for the same id
    String id = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_CARD_ID);
    if (timerHashMap.containsKey(id)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[onStartCommand] timer already exists");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    //create and start timer
    Log.i(TAG, "[onStartCommand] schedule timer");
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new CounterTask(id), MAX_MILLIES_WITHOUT_UPDATE);
    timerHashMap.put(id, timer);
    // storeTimers();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

I also tried to store the timer map in the shared preferences but later on I realized that thsi was kind of stupid because the timers should continue and serializing a timer to store it was also not possible (and as I said kind of stupid ;-))

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JobScheduler` (or some variations of it).

There are `Minimum Latency` and `Periodic` options to schedule the Job to run after 30 days.

Refer this article for more info: [Scheduling jobs like a pro with JobScheduler](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129)

There is [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html) in the latest Support Library and [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-) for backward compatibility.